# MKMapView not updating overlay correctly after changing its boundingMapRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Below is very simple custom overlay object:

```
@interface Overlay : NSObject <MKOverlay>
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MKMapRect boundingMapRect;
@end

@implementation Overlay
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.78577, -122.40645);
        _boundingMapRect.origin = MKMapPointForCoordinate(_coordinate);
        _boundingMapRect.size = MKMapSizeMake(200, 200);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

OverlayView is also very straightforward:

```
@implementation OverlayView
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    Overlay* overlay = (Overlay*)[self overlay];
    CGRect r = [self rectForMapRect:overlay.boundingMapRect];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, r);
}
@end
```

And its `boundingMapRect` property updated on button click:

```
-(IBAction)onUpdateOverlayBtn:(id)sender
{
    _overlay.boundingMapRect = MKMapRectInset(_overlay.boundingMapRect, -3000, -3000);
    [_overlayView setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:_overlay.boundingMapRect];
}
```

The problem appears when MKMapView is zoomed in (right side):

[image: screenshot]

[Test Xcode project on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/onegray/mkoverlaytest)

Comment: You're accessing attributes of _boundingMapRect straight away without initialising it, can that be done?

Comment: No, look at the `-[Overlay init]` method. Initially it is initialized with a small rect, and it displays fine until `boundingMapRect` gets updated on button click.

Comment: It's the `init` method I am looking at. You set `_boundingMapRect.origin` without first setting up `_boundingMapRect`. If you tell me it works I'll have to believe you, but I'm surprised.

Comment: Why not? `MKMapRect` is just a simple struct (like `CGRect`), so I can fill its fields separately.